# How to add type definitions to composed enhancers with Flow?

Tags: reactjs, redux, flowtype, react-apollo

Flow is driving me crazy. Even though it's really comfortable to use with some sort of "basic" code, it's hard to type when making use of HOCs (as you can see in some of my last questions ...).

So, I've got a component which:

- **needs** an prop from the parent component (`activeProject`)
- connects to a Redux store
- uses data from the Redux store to query data with GraphQL
- renders some components which make use of redux & GraphQL data

For sure I could skip to type this part of my code, but I like the idea to be type-safe within the whole app.

That's my current implementation of the described component:

```
// @flow

import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { compose, graphql } from 'react-apollo'
import type { OperationComponent, QueryProps } from 'react-apollo'
import type { Connector } from 'react-redux'

import { Loading } from 'components'

import { getProjectList } from 'queries'

import ProjectFilter from './Filter'
import ProjectList from './List'

import { Wrapper } from './elements'

type GraphQLResponse = {
  customers: {
    [string | number]: any
  }
}

type InputProps = {
  activeProject: number
}

type StoreProps = {
  showArchivedProjects: boolean
}

type GraphQLProps = GraphQLResponse & QueryProps

type GrapQLInputProps = InputProps & StoreProps

type CombinedProps = GraphQLProps & StoreProps & InputProps

const withGraphQL: OperationComponent<GraphQLResponse, GrapQLInputProps, GraphQLProps> = graphql(getProjectList, {
  options: ({ showArchivedProjects }) => ({
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
    variables: {
      archived: showArchivedProjects
    }
  }),
  props: ({ data }) => ({ ...data })
})

const withStore: Connector<*, StoreProps> = connect(
  state => ({
    showArchivedProjects: state.projects.showArchivedProjects
  }),
  {}
)

const enhanced = compose(
  withGraphQL,
  withStore
)

const ProjectSidebar = enhanced(({ activeProject, loading, customers }: CombinedProps) => {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <ProjectFilter />

      {loading && <Loading isLoading={true} float={true} top="calc(100vh - 100px)" />}
      {customers && <ProjectList activeProject={activeProject} customers={customers} />}
    </Wrapper>
  )
})

export default ProjectSidebar
```

Running `flow` on this code, I get the following error on `withStore` (inside `compose`):

> Cannot call compose because:
>
> • Either function [1] is incompatible with statics of React.Component [2].
>   • Or property customers is missing in StoreProps [3] but exists in GraphQLResponse [4] in the first argument.

Why should my `StoreProps` know about `customers`? What's wrong with this attempt?

I'm very sure that I'm using some of the tools wrong, but after looking (for hours) for examples/apps/docs, that make use of `react-apollo`, `redux` and `flow`, I just gave up ...